# activity shows blank result?

Tags: android

I am developing an app using api to display list, and listview contains data. But when i run the project, activity shows blank result and logcat shown 'no value of "program"(i.e.array name)' message.
How do i show result of following code?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        // Declare Variables
        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonarray;
        ListView listview;
        ListViewAdapter adapter;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

        static String AID = "asanaid";
        static String ANAME = "asananame";
        static String DURATION = "duration";
        static String IMGURL = "imgeurl";
        static String IMGVERSION = "imgeversion";
        static String AUDIOURL = "audiourl";
        static String AUDIOVERSION = "audioversion";


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Get the view from listview_main.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_relaxation_lv);
            // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
            new DownloadJSON().execute();
        }

        // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                // Set progressdialog title
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Create an array
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://www.....");

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("program");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put("asanaid", jsonobject.getString("asanaid"));
                        map.put("asananame", jsonobject.getString("asananame"));
                        map.put("duration", jsonobject.getString("duration"));
                        map.put("imgeurl", jsonobject.getString("imgeurl"));
                        map.put("imgeversion", jsonobject.getString("imgeversion"));
                        map.put("audiourl", jsonobject.getString("audiourl"));
                        map.put("audioversion", jsonobject.getString("audioversion"));

                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
                listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
                // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
                // Set the adapter to the ListView
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Close the progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }


    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView tvAname, tvId, imgUrl, imgVersion, audioUrl, audioVersion, duration;
    ImageView imgPose;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.relaxationlv_single_item, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    tvAname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lv_aname);
    tvAname.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.ANAME));

    tvId = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lv_aid);
    tvId.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.AID));

    duration = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lv_duration);
    duration.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.DURATION));

    imgVersion = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lv_imgversion);
    imgVersion.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.IMGURL));

    audioVersion = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lv_audioversion);
    audioVersion.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.AUDIOVERSION));

    audioUrl= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lv_audiourl);
    audioUrl.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.AUDIOURL));

    imgPose = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lv_imgurl);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.IMGURL), imgPose);

    // Capture ListView item click
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Get the position
            resultp = data.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, RelaxationLvAudioPlayerActivity1.class);
            intent.putExtra("asanaid", resultp.get(MainActivity.AID));
            intent.putExtra("asananame", resultp.get(MainActivity.ANAME));
            intent.putExtra("duration", resultp.get(MainActivity.DURATION));
            intent.putExtra("imgeurl", resultp.get(MainActivity.IMGURL));
            intent.putExtra("imgeversion", resultp.get(MainActivity.IMGVERSION));
            intent.putExtra("audiourl", resultp.get(MainActivity.AUDIOURL));
            intent.putExtra("audioversion", resultp.get(MainActivity.AUDIOVERSION));
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    return itemView;
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your logs please.

Comment: 07-20 14:54:27.110 26060-26093/com.sca.itfms.yogapointdb E/Error: No value for program
07-20 14:54:27.110 26060-26093/com.sca.itfms.yogapointdb W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for program

Comment: This probably means your json doesn't have any element with the name program. It probably breaks at the point jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("program");

Comment: Can you paste your json response as well

Comment: @kapsym: i have data in  array "program"

Comment: Please check my answer below

Comment: Most probably some field is missing in your JSON Response. Try printing all the fields

Comment: `W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for program` this line shows that the response you are getting does not have any value for program so an exception is thrown. which results in no data being shown.

Comment: can you post the json? it looks like  jsonobject.getJSONArray("program"); has an error

Comment: @Rohu Can you add your json response here for us to verify the code.

Comment: I think you should probably just consider rewriting your Activity code with the help of http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ , [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), and [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the JSONException -

Please check if one of the following field is missing in your JSON Response -

```
map.put("asanaid", jsonobject.getString("asanaid"));
                        map.put("asananame", jsonobject.getString("asananame"));
                        map.put("duration", jsonobject.getString("duration"));
                        map.put("imgeurl", jsonobject.getString("imgeurl"));
                        map.put("imgeversion", jsonobject.getString("imgeversion"));
                        map.put("audiourl", jsonobject.getString("audiourl"));
                        map.put("audioversion", jsonobject.getString("audioversion"));
```

You can check this buy printing the value of jsonobject.getString("asaname") and so on.

Or the another case might be the value is of different dataType. E.g. audioversion you are trying to get as String but in JSON it is type of Integer.

Comment: have you tried to print all the values. Sometimes the value might be of different datatype.

Comment: ImageUrl and version dataType should be in String. Check your JSON file for that in your browser

Comment: url: http://www.yogapoint.com/iOS/images/relaxation-programs/default-image.jpg  and version: 0 in this type

Comment: version might be an Integer. Try jsonobject.getInt("audioversion")

Comment: First print the values outside the try block to check